# Linux: Getting the kernel buffer size for a socket

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, buffer

I have a C application which receives a lot of data over a TCP socket. Is it somehow possible to get the kernel buffer size for that file descriptor / socket? I would like to know how much data is still in the kernel for the file-descriptor I have.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `SIOCINQ`/`FIONREAD` `ioctl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html):

```
int bytes_left;
ioctl(sock, FIONREAD, &bytes_left);
```

This “returns the amount of queued unread data in the receive buffer.” `SIOCINQ` is defined in `linux/sockios.h` (on Linux), `FIONREAD` in `sys/ioctl.h`.

To retrieve the buffer capacity for the socket, use [`getsockopt` with `SO_RCVBUF`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html).